# QRadioButton игнорирует QLabel

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Мой код

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QRadioButton, QHBoxLayout, QButtonGroup, 
    QApplication, QWidget, QLabel)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *



class Label(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Label, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.parent.click()

class Radio(QRadioButton): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Radio, self).__init__(parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        lay.setSpacing(0)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setText('rb0')
        self.label = Label(self)
        self.label.setText('test0098908uhjhjk9')

        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())


        self.setStyleSheet('QRadioButton{background:red} QRadioButton::indicator{ text:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)}')


        self.label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.label.setStyleSheet('padding:10;margin10;background:green')
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        print('radio-2 h - {}'.format(self.height()))
        print('radio-2 w - {}'.format(self.width()))
        print('label h -{}'.format(self.label.height()))
        print('label w -{}'.format(self.label.width()))

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(140, 34))


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._dictRB = {                                            
            'rb0': False,
            'rb1': False,
            'rb2': False,
            'rb3': False,
        }

        self.main_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)



        self.buttonGroup = QButtonGroup()
        self.attr_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.attr_layout)


        self.rb0 = Radio()                             #QRadioButton() # 'rb0'


        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.rb0.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.rb0.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)





        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb0)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb0)

        self.rb1 = QRadioButton('rb1')
        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb1)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb1)               

        self.rb2 = QRadioButton('rb2')
        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb2)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb2) 

        self.rb3 = QRadioButton('rb3')                               
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb3)                         

        self.buttonGroup.buttonClicked.connect(self.check_button)

    def check_button(self, radioButton):
        if self._dictRB[radioButton.text()]:
            self._dictRB[radioButton.text()] = False
            self._dictRB['rb3'] = True
            self.rb3.setChecked(True)              
        else:
            for b in self._dictRB:
                self._dictRB[b] = False
            self._dictRB[radioButton.text()] = True

        print("Button -> `{} - {}`".format(radioButton.text(), radioButton.isChecked()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    #w.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 400))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Мне нужно чтобы Radio() не было меньше QLabel.
И вела себя примерно как если бы QLabel был подключен к Layout находясь внутри QWidget
С сохраненым margin и padding.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался использовать setMinimumSize() но QLabel всегда равен 30Х100 пока вручную не укажешь размер.
Но постоянно просчитывать margin, padding, font-size, border, и другие qss свойства слишком неудобно.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QRadioButton, QHBoxLayout, QButtonGroup, 
    QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QSizePolicy)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Radio(QRadioButton): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Radio, self).__init__(parent)

        lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        lay.setSpacing(0)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setText('0')

# ++  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self._pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
        self.setIcon(QIcon('rb0.png'))
        self.setIconSize(QSize(150, 150))
        self.setFixedHeight(37)
        self.setMinimumWidth(125)
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText('test0098908uhjhjk9')
        self.label.setMinimumWidth(100)  # +

#        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Minimum)                 # +++
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.setStyleSheet('background: red')
#       self.label.setStyleSheet('padding: 10; margin10;   background:green')
# ???                                      ??  ????????
        self.label.setStyleSheet('padding:  0; margin: 10; background: green; color: #fff')  # +++

        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        print('radio-2 h - {}'.format(self.height()))
        print('radio-2 w - {}'.format(self.width()))
        print('label h -{}'.format(self.label.height()))
        print('label w -{}'.format(self.label.width()))

        #self.setMinimumSize(QSize(self.label.height(), self.label.height()))

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionButton()
        self.initStyleOption(opt)
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)   
        # нарисовать основную кнопку        
        self.style().drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_PushButtonLabel, opt, qp, self)
        if self._pixmap.isNull():
            return   

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.setIconSize(QSize(self.width()+120, self.height()+120))

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(30, 30)
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._dictRB = {                                            
            '0'  : False,
            'rb1': False,
            'rb2': False,
            'rb3': False,
        }

        self.main_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.buttonGroup = QButtonGroup()
        self.attr_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.attr_layout)

        self.rb0 = Radio()                             #QRadioButton() # 'rb0'
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.rb0.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.rb0.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb0)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb0)
        self.rb1 = QRadioButton('rb1')
        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb1)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb1)               
        self.rb2 = QRadioButton('rb2')
        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb2)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb2) 
        self.rb3 = QRadioButton('rb3')                               
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb3)                         
        self.buttonGroup.buttonClicked.connect(self.check_button)

    def check_button(self, radioButton):
        if self._dictRB[radioButton.text()]:
            self._dictRB[radioButton.text()] = False
            self._dictRB['rb3'] = True
            self.rb3.setChecked(True)              
        else:
            for b in self._dictRB:
                self._dictRB[b] = False
            self._dictRB[radioButton.text()] = True
        print("Нажата кнопка -> `{} - {}`".format(radioButton.text(), radioButton.isChecked()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 400))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**rb0.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне нужно что бы геометрия радио автоматически подстраивалась под лейбл. ведь текст может быть разной длины. и  margin с padding тоже.

Comment: @orlatym  что вам мешает делать это динамический?

Comment: Проблема в том что я не вижу разницы между `self.setIconSize(QSize(150, 150)) self.setFixedHeight(37) self.setMinimumWidth(125)` и `self.setMinimumSize(QSize(140, 34))`